# Octopress choose aside for each page

Tags: octopress

I have several pages on my blog that are quite specific and I know exactly what links I would like to appear on the sidebar of each page.

The only way I know how to control sidebar content is to designate certain asides to appear with certain layouts.

In my case, these pages do not each need a unique layout (`per-se`), they just need a different set of asides.   So I am reluctant to create a separate layout for each page just so I can control the asides with more precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, you'll need a new layout in which you can specify specific page_asides.  There's a good example of the customizations you'll need to make here:  [New Plain Page Layout for Octopress](https://web.archive.org/web/20131207035439/http://vigodome.com/blog/2011/12/18/hello-world/)

Comment: I believe you misunderstood me slightly.  I was not opposed to creating a new layout, only to creating a separate layout for each page.  Regardless, your answer was just what I was looking for.  Once the suggested layout is created, posts using this layout can specify the asides to be used within the YAML at the top of the post - a feature I actually desired but dared not ask for fear of being greedy.

Comment: @gyurisc You're right, the link is broken.  If you really want that content, you'll have to resort to the Wayback machine:  https://web.archive.org/web/20131207035439/http://vigodome.com/blog/2011/12/18/hello-world/